# How to add link on menu nav hugo site

Tags: yaml, hugo, blogdown

How can I add a direct link onto a nav item in a menu opposed to a reference to a section?

in my config.toml, I've added a link but it first places the baseurl in front of it:

```
[menu]

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Summary"
    URL = "services"
    weight = 2

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Contact"
    URL = "contact-us"
    weight = 3

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Methods"
    URL = "blog"
    weight = 4

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Français"
    url = "https://example.com/" #this is the link I want to add
    weight = 5
```

I found [this post](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/active-links-in-menu/8717/11), but don't know html so am unsure where to add a change in the layout/partials/navigation.html file.

My suspicion is it's somewhere in this range of the partial.

```
                {{ if .IsHome }}
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navigation-menu">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#body">{{ with $.Site.Params.home }}{{ . }}{{ end }}</a></li>
                                {{ range $.Site.Menus.nav }}
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#{{ .URL }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
                                {{ end }}
                        </ul>
                </div>
                {{ else }}
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navigation-menu">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="{{ $.Site.BaseURL }}#body">{{ with $.Site.Params.home }}{{ . }}{{ end }}</a></li>
                                {{ range $.Site.Menus.nav }}
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="{{ $.Site.BaseURL }}#{{ .URL | absURL }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
                                {{ end }}
                        </ul>
                </div>
                {{ end }}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation URLs are not handled great by this theme. Try to replace

the `href="{{ $.Site.BaseURL }}#{{ .URL | absURL }}"` to `href="{{ .URL |relURL }}"`. It should work for both internal and external links

```
                {{ if .IsHome }}
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navigation-menu">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#body">{{ with $.Site.Params.home }}{{ . }}{{ end }}</a></li>
                                {{ range $.Site.Menus.nav }}
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="{{ .URL | relURL }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
                                {{ end }}
                        </ul>
                </div>
                {{ else }}
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navigation-menu">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="{{ $.Site.BaseURL }}#body">{{ with $.Site.Params.home }}{{ . }}{{ end }}</a></li>
                                {{ range $.Site.Menus.nav }}
                                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="{{ .URL | relURL }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
                                {{ end }}
                        </ul>
                </div>
                {{ end }}
```

and in your config.yaml, add "/" before the internal link.

```
baseurl = "/"

[menu]

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Summary"
    URL = "/services"
    weight = 2

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Contact"
    URL = "/contact-us"
    weight = 3

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Methods"
    URL = "/blog"
    weight = 4

    [[menu.nav]]
    name = "Français"
    url = "https://example.com/" #this is the link I want to add
    weight = 5
```

Comment: Thank you, altough now it is taking the argument and pasting it in front of the URL, locally as http://127.0.0.1:4321/example.com, and to see the site as https://state-of-open-smart-cities-2019.netlify.com/example.com ideally it would be linking it to the url arg I'm giving in the config file

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated my answer. Also you could have a look at  yihui's repo to get some idea of how to correctly setup the navigation bar

Comment: Thanks - will check in the morning, and I will, I was thinking it was a unique to this theme issue but I guess more of a general HTML question

Comment: Cheers thanks, added the full link with // but removed / for the site nav URLs.